# OpenCL kernel with generic data type

Tags: opencl

When writing code for kernels, is it possible to specify a generic data type so that copying the kernel for each used data type is not necessary? Currently I'm using preprocessor macros to define the whole function with various data types:

```
#define REDUCTION(type) __kernel void reduce_##type##_f(__global __read_only type* a) \
{ \
// do something
} \

REDUCTION(float)
REDUCTION(float2)
```

This however is not very comfortable. Is there some type specifier like `gentype` available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that starting with OpenCL 2.1 which let you use C++ and templates in kernel code [Knronos's OpenCL page](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/).

With that, you can simply write:

```
template <class T>
void reduce_f(__global __read_only T* a) { 
   // do something
}
```

However I am not 100% sure templates would be available in the definition of `__kernel` functions. If that is not the case, you would still need to wrap the kernel declaration within preprocessing macros as so:

```
#define REDUCTION(type) __kernel void reduce_##type##_f(__global __read_only type* a) \
{ \
  return reduce_t(a); \
}

REDUCTION(float)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your macro have backslashes at ends-of-lines?